# how to properly use HttpClient wrapped as a Class Libary

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, class-library

In my C# app I need to have 2 distinct parts:
1) a Class Library, which wraps HttpClient, takes parameters, such as URI, and a JSON object to be POSTED, and invokes the POST method on an instance of HttpClient:

```
static async Task CreateCustomer()
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://10.211.55.2:8080/");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");

                var customer = new Customer() { Name = "Gizmo",  Address = "123 Widget lane" };
                var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("/api/customer", customer);
                var p = response;
            }
        }
```

2) A Windows Console app, which imports this Class Library, and invokes this CreateCustomer method, passing the actual parameter values for the URI and the Customer JSON object:

```
static async Task EnvokeCreateCustomer()
        {
            Customer customer = new Customer {Name="",Address="" };
            var URI = "http://my_api:8080/Customer";
            RestClient.Client restClient = new RestClient.Client();
            restClient.CreateCustomer(URI, customer);
        }
```

This code runs, but it is not event hitting my API, blows right passed it, and does nothing. Same issue with the GET API.

Is there a proven way to create such Class Libraries, which can be invoked by a Console app?

Comment: Your library `CreateCustomer()` accepts no parameter then how come you are calling with parameter?

Comment: You are not awaiting the last line, modify it like this: await restClient.CreateCustomer(URI, customer); And do you await the call to EnvokeCreateCustomer()?

Comment: @PeterBons, just because it's async doesn't restrict you to await on it.

Comment: @Rahul, no but it is best practice. Exception handling is cumbersome when calls are not awaited, and since he doesn't handel any it is hard to see if and what might go wrong.

Comment: @PeterBons, NO it's not. Whether to await the call or not depends on your need/requirement. If you want the call to be over before your next code statement (may be you want to perform something on the return data) then await else it's not needed at all.

Comment: @Rahul David made my point ;-). I get your point as well but I do wonder Eugene did intend a fire and forget mechanism. And since it is not working as expected...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't await the method call:

```
await restClient.CreateCustomer(URI, customer);
```

Depending on the application host this may or may not make a *noticeable* difference.  In a **console application**, where the application may simply do its thing and immediately terminate, it makes an enormous difference.

Not to mention any errors received in the process may go entirely unnoticed if the call is not awaited.  So it's *possible* that there is a problem and it's trying to tell you what the problem is, but your code is simply ignoring it.

Surely there's a compiler warning pointing this out.  Never ignore compiler warnings.

---

Side note: How does this code even compile?  This:

```
restClient.CreateCustomer(URI, customer);
```

can't be calling this:

```
static async Task CreateCustomer()
```

If what you're showing us isn't your actual code, then all bets are off as far as answers go.